# Record status of http call to show in the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What I am wanting to do, is record the status of a HTTP call, so that I can give the user some feedback in the UI, rather than either succeeding silently, or showing a grim error.

What I have done is created a `Result` class. For ease, I will show the simple class, but I also have this as a generic class, so it can also contain data.

The `Result` class:

```cs
public class Result
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }

        public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

        public Result() { }

        public Result(bool isSuccess)
        {
            IsSuccess = isSuccess;
        }

        public Result(string errors, bool isSuccess)
        {
            IsSuccess = isSuccess;
            Error = errors;
        }

        public Result(string errors, bool isSuccess, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        {
            Error = errors;
            IsSuccess = isSuccess;
            HttpStatusCode = statusCode;
        }
    }
```

When I make a call to the API I am using, I use the `Result` class, as below:

```cs
public async Task<Result> UpdateColour(GrapeColour grapeColour)
        {
            var body = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grapeColour), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var client = _httpClient.CreateClient(ApiNames.WineApi);

            var response = await client.PutAsync(_grapeColourUrl, body).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return new Result(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return await HttpResponseHandler.HandleError(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

Where my `HttpResponseHandler` does some stuff, but fundamentally writes the bool `isSuccessful` to false, give an error message, and set the status code.

This all lives in my `Domain` layer.

I then pass this over to the web side of my project, here is the controller method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditColour(Result<EditableGrapeColourViewModel> model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(new Result<EditableGrapeColourViewModel>(model.Data));
            }

            var domainGrapeColour = _grapeMapper.Map<Domain.Grape.GrapeColour>(model.Data);

            var saveResult = await _grapeService.SaveColour(domainGrapeColour, SaveType.Update).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (saveResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("EditColour", "Grape", new { id = model.Data.Id, IsSuccess = true });
            }

            var viewModel = new Result<EditableGrapeColourViewModel>(saveResult.IsSuccess, saveResult.Error, model.Data);

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

So the model I use in for the viewmodel and the view has to be the `Result<T>` so I can access the `isSuccessful` and the error message to show the user.

I use automapper to map from my domain object, to an object in the web project, but I use the domain `Result`.

So my question is two fold; Is what I am doing a decent solution for what I want to do? And if it is, should I be using the domain `Result` object as I am?

Comment: Since the "success/fail" nature of the result can be defined based on the HTTP status code alone, why separately record the two? By default, HTTP 2xx is a success and HTTP 4xx and 5xx are a failure. Is there any particular reason why you're trying to manually define a success rather than relying on the HTTP status code?

Comment: For simplicity in the view, so I can simply check the `isSuccess` bool to show/hide a div which will either show save successful, or an error message. I use the HTTP status code on there, just to be helpful should something go wrong and a screen shot be sent etc. It's a fair point, maybe I could simply check to see if the status code starts with a 4/5 to determine what to show

Comment: Please learn to use `this` instead of copy-pasting code between constructors: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors

Comment: You're also not handling exceptions. What if the URL you call is off-line, for instance?

Comment: @BCdotWEB that is something I am going to handle with middleware. What I am wanting to know at the moment is around how I am using the `Result` class

Comment: @Keith Yeah the existence of `IsSuccess` isn't an issue, but I'd make it a calculated property based on httpstatus instead of having to set it individually.